# How to match one 'x' but not one or both of xs in 'xx' globally in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working with javascript and want to match the single 'o' but not 'oo' in 'cocoon' or 'Bob's saloon'.
I've tried

```
/o(?!o)/gi
```

but doesn't work. It yields 'o,o', instead of only 'o'.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you want to match the first o or every o individually?

Comment: You need `/(?<!o)o(?!o)/gi`

Comment: I want to capture only single o's instead of double and your solution works fine :) but unfortunately mozilla firefox does not support negative lookbehinds yet. Is there a workaround for this?